# Converting JSON to XML null?

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net

When I convert XML to JSON and the XML field null I get something I get a null returned in the JSON, is this the expected JSON output? im using it for a web service.

Could I turn null off, so that it displays blank/empty.

XML

```
<GetItemRequest>
    <ApplicationCrediential>
        <ConsumerKey></ConsumerKey>
        <ConsumerSecret></ConsumerSecret>
    </ApplicationCrediential>
</GetItemRequest>
```

JSON

```
{
  "GetItemRequest": {
    "ApplicationCrediential": {
      "ConsumerKey": null,
      "ConsumerSecret": null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There isn't a value, and `null` generally indicates that, so it makes sense to me.

Comment: How are you even doing the conversion?  Are you using a third party library or something of your own making?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I thought the response is suppose to be like this ...... {
  "GetItemRequest": {
    "ApplicationCrediential": {
      "ConsumerKey": "",
      "ConsumerSecret": ""
    }
  }
}

Comment: @YYY using JSON.NET c# library, im wondering how to turn null off?

Comment: Yeah, in JSON.NET it is going to handle empty strings as nulls, which is semantically correct for JSON and more consistent for .net since null can be implicitly converted to anything, but string.Empty is still a string and will break various conversions.  You would have to modify JSON.NET itself to change this behavior unless they have added some extra JSON object decorators since I used it last.

Comment: You are right, and also according to IBM, "null" is the correct response, http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6r1mx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wbit.610.help.config.doc/topics/rjsonnullunsempprops.html